# How to prevent specified table content from being altered?

Tags: configuration, static, lua, serial-port, lua-table

I got this (very simplified) scenario while coding a port handling routine for a micro-controller.
3 files

file1:

```
table = {var1 = true, var2 = true, var 3 = false, var 4 = true}
function dosomething()
    dosomething
    --defines bools in table by whatever condition is present
end
```

file2: Actually a Menu. If an input is given the corresponding boolean in table is changed.

```
function selection()
     selection = interprete_input()
     invertVars(selection)
end

function invertVars(selection)
         table.selection = not table.selection
 end
```

file3: in the simplified scenario, only uses the bools@table to know it to operate for the given case or not. The indices are used as values as well. For example one entry in table could be ' ["ttyS0"] = true ' so I know the function whether should run for COM-Port ttyS0 or not

```
function needsVarsFromTable()
    for v,k in pairs(table)
        if k then
            --the actual function uses true/false as indicator to know if to run 
            --for  the entry of table or not.
            the_actual_function_that_needs_v(v)
        end
end
```

The Problem now is:

The Table contains 19 entries. 2 of them have to be static. They're false and can never be true. But in my script it's possible to make them true what will cause errors.

Unfortunately Lua doesn't bring static variables. How can I prevent them from be altered by other functions? These other functions still have to be able to read them.

I don't want to check for every var@Table if the reading function is allowed to alter, due performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PiL 13.4.5](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.5.html) provides an example of read-only table, read the whole chapter if you are not familiar with metatables and metamethods.

To protect the field `"var2"`, a little modification to the code in the book can do it:

```
local t = {var1 = true, var2 = true, var3 = false, var4 = true}

function protect_field(t)
    local proxy = {}
    local mt = { -- create metatable
    __index = t,
    __newindex = function (t, k, v)
        if k == 'var2' then
            error("attempt to update var2 field")
        else
            rawset(t, k, v)
        end
    end
    }
    setmetatable(proxy, mt)
    return proxy
end

t = protect_field(t)
```

Now it's legal to update field `"var1"`:

```
t.var1 = false
```

But `t.var2 = false` will raise an error.

Comment: Okay, but, `rawset(t,"var2", "can, too")`.

Comment: @TomBlodget that will only set it in the proxy table. not the original table.

Comment: @daurnimator Good point. But it's still security by obscurity: `rawset(getmetatable(t).__index,"var2", "can, too")`. The technique is good for expressing read-only intentions.

Comment: if you're worried about this, set `__metatable` and don't give anyone access to `debug.getmetatable`. But at this point, people are just shooting themselves in the foot on purpose.